# Setting an array to null and then updating it in useEffect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React. I've a MealList component to which I'm passing a set of props, based on which it make a data call and updates an array of meals, which I display in a table.

```
const MealList = (props) => {
    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchMeals = async (userId, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime) => {
            ...
            return resp;
        };
        fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'), props.fromDate, props.toDate, props.fromTime, props.toTime).then(r => {
            setMeals([...meals, ...r.data])//The fetched data is stored in an array here.
        });
    }, [props]);
    console.log(props.fromDate);
    return (
        <div style={{width: '70%'}}>
            ...
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {meals.map((meal, index) => (<Meal key={meal.id} count={index +1} meal={meal}/>))}//And displayed here
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>

    )
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that using the spread syntax `setMeals([...meals, ...r.data])` appends to the existing list everytime MealList is updated via the props.

My question is how can I set the meals array back to null and then update only the new values? I've tried this:

```
fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'), props.fromDate, props.toDate, props.fromTime, props.toTime).then(r => {
            setMeals([]);
            setMeals([...meals, ...r.data])
        });
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: can't you try setMeals(r.data) ?

Comment: Tried this it doesn't load the data at all, I think because of the asynchronous nature of the call.

Comment: is it fetching the data from your function?

Comment: according to me it should re-render after setMeals(r.data) is called whether it is async or sync.

Comment: It is re-rendering with the old and new data together, maybe you should read the question one more time.

Comment: But `setMeals(r.data)` doesn't work at all.

Comment: So when you fetch the data from the server, you already have some of that data in your `meals` variable, but you want to add only new meals? You have unwanted duplication of data, am I right?

Comment: have you tried  ```setMeals([...r.data])``` ?

Comment: I believe is this less about React and more about understanding modern javascript. There is no point of calling `setMeals([])` right before `setMeals([...meals, ...r.data])`. Just call it once with the data you want set into that state object.

Comment: Info: What is resp? the return value of a fetch() call? Something else? If it is, what kind of response are you getting on your resp.data?

Comment: @yonki I want to set the array to an empty state and only add the newly fetched data - I think I mention this very clearly in the question.

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja the whole point of the question is that it isn't working. I wanted to present the stuff that I have tried and not worked.

Comment: @ZoiloReyes the resp.data is the exact array that needs to be copied to meals for global access.

Comment: In your question, you say that the new items are being appended onto the array with the old items. Is the `meals` state object the old objects? If so, why are you adding it back into state along with the response? If you want to update the meal state with just the response from an api, instead of `setMeals([...meals, ...resp.data])` try `setMeals(resp.data)` which is functionally equal to `setMeals([...resp.data])`.

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja if you read the comments above, someone already suggested that, I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: here is an example @MelissaStewart https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-usestate-svnmpn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same effect of the splicing you should use

```
 setMeals(r.data.slice());
```

as otherwise the reference to `r.data` is passed and it can make a difference if that object is mutated after the `setMeals` call.

When you pass an array to a function in Javascript the function doesn't receive a **copy** of the array, but a reference to the original object you passed. For example:

```
 let x = [1,2,3], y = null;

 function foo(xx) {
     y = xx;
 }
 foo(x);
 console.log(y); // gives [1, 2, 3]
 x[1] = 99;
 console.log(y); // gives [1, 99, 3]
```

Apparently the code in `fetchMeals` (that we don't see) **reuses** the `r.data` array and this creates the problem if you don't make a copy. I would probably classify this as a (design) bug in `fetchMeals` as given the interface I'd expect to get a fresh answer and not a reused one that I must copy.

Note also that

```
x.slice()
```

is the same as

```
[...x]
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the reasoning, but trying this now.

Comment: This works for me, can you please elaborate a little on why `setMeals(r.data)` didn't work.

Comment: @MelissaStewart doing `setMeals([...resp.data])` and `setMeals(resp.data.splice())` both create new arrays that look the same as the original array. The reason you would do this is because in the case the response array (from resp.data) is mutated (changed/updated), the updated array object won't be affected.

Comment: @EugeneSunic No I didn't, it just wasn't a part of the topic. In the question, the spread operator is used. I was comparing it to slice because it was used in this answer.

Comment: tl;dr: every time you want to update array in state, you need to create a new array for the reason that React will compare your arrays by reference between re-renders. And if reference stays the same, update will likely not happen. So the suggested approaches (`setMeals(r.data)`, `setMeals(r.data.slice())`, `setMeals([...r.data])`) will all work. Your r.data is expected to be a new object every time you receive it from the backend

Comment: @Max . ```And if reference stays the same, update will likely not happen``` omit likely, it just won't happen.

Comment: Should've added that this only applies to react hooks. setState creates new copy automatically.

Comment: Looks to me like addition of `setMeals([...meals,` was the problem the author of the question was obviously facing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example (trying to mimic your code):

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-usestate-svnmpn?file=MealList.js

The problem is with data mutation, you have to remain immutable if you want new changes to re-render you component and apply the update.

```
  const MealList = props => {
  const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMeals = async (userId, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime) => {
      return await new Promise(res =>
        setTimeout(
          _ =>
            res({
              data: [
                { id: 1, name: "sphagetti" },
                { id: 2, name: "salad" },
                { id: 3, name: "soup" },
                { id: 4, name: "bacon and eggs" }
              ]
            }),
          2000
        )
      );
    };
    fetchMeals(1, "date1", "date2", "time", "time2").then(r =>
      setMeals([...r.data])
    );
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "70%" }}>
      {!meals.length && <p>wait 2 seconds...</p>}
      {meals.map((meal, index) => (
        <div key={meal.id} count={index + 1} meal={meal}>
          {meal.id + ". " + meal.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this approach? I believe reducer fits into your need better than simple state changes. Keep in mind that this is simple example. You can move props into the action and do the fetching in another file to keep your component clean and separate concerns.

You can also run code snippet here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-frog-y2e6j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const mealsReducer = ({ meals }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_MEALS": {
      return {
        meals: action.meals
      };
    }
    // no default
  }
};
const MealList = ({ fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(mealsReducer, { meals: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMeals = (userId, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime) => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: [{ id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), name: "blabla" }]
      });
    };
    fetchMeals(0, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime).then(({ data }) =>
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_MEALS", meals: data })
    );
  }, [fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {state.meals.map((meal, index) => (
        <li key={meal.id}>{ meal.name }</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default MealList;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. `useReducer` was exactly what I wanted. I think I was halfway to implementing it with `useState` (and had bugs in my version) until I read through your solution.